# How to set up raw_id_fields in django-rest-framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

In Django admin, one can set up a raw_id_fields in order to have a search widget instead of a select box. This is very neat to spare up a lot of database queries when the foreign key table is huge.

What is the equivalent in the Django Rest Framework browsable views?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django Rest Framework 3 no longer supports widget attribute on serializer field. But to get your browsable API even usable, try changing `style` attribute to use `'base_template': 'input.html'` as in following example:

```
class CustomerAddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = serializers.IntegerField(source='customer_id' style={'base_template': 'input.html', 'placeholder': "Customer ID"})
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomerAddress
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'street', 'zip', 'city')
```

This way your huge `select` tag with thousands foreign key `options` will change to simple text `input`. For more info check docs at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#handling-choicefield-with-large-numbers-of-items

Comment: Is there any way to do this dynamically in the class's `__init__`?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to support this currently. I'm pretty sure that pull requests would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding what Carlton says, although it'd be worth discussing in a ticket prior to taking a stab at the implementation.

Alternatively, you might want to take a look at using an autocomplete widget...

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#autocomplete